# How to get Class responsible for creating large number of primitive bytes?

Tags: memory-leaks, jvm, out-of-memory, monitoring, heap-memory

**Problem:**
Our application (in Java with Vertx) is taking more than 10 GB of Heap Memory. It is creating memory leak in application.

**What I tried:**
To Analyse the reason for this, I have taken heap dump using jmap and analyzed using jhat. The result of jhat is just showing that somewhere byte itself is taking 8 GB of memory with millions of instance. But every array or collection internally uses byte. I am not using byte directly in my project.

**Need help in:**
Please suggest me the way I can debug the class in my code which is responsible for memory leak. Any tool which can show the hierarchy along with the instance count.

Comment: java version? lots of byte array instances _usually_ mean lots of Strings. and any heap dump analyzer should be able to tell you where all those byte arrays are coming from...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Eclipse MAT to analyze and trace the "Path to GC Roots": https://www.eclipse.org/mat/about/screenshots.php.